# Load original texture (.mtl) again after changing material

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx, assimp

To load an .obj file I use the HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.Assimp.Importer.
This loads the 3d model and applies the default material as defined in the mtl.

```
var loader = new Importer();
return loader.Load(path); // returns HelixToolkitScene
```

This works as expected.

I can change the material of the model by using

```
public static void ApplyMaterial(HelixToolkitScene scene, Material material)
{
  if (material != null)
  {
    if (scene != null)
    {
      if (scene.Root != null)
      {
        foreach (var node in scene.Root.Traverse())
        {
          if (node is MaterialGeometryNode m)
          {
            m.Material = material;                
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At some point, I want to remove any materials and display the model in its initial state (after loading, with the default materials defined in the .mtl file).

How can I reload the original .mtl file?
Do I have to reload the entire model (import from the .obj) again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you have to set the property for the imported asset in the used View-Model of helix and it should re-create the model data.

If you want to avoid this you can just access the specific material-property directly. For instance:

```
 Material mat = ((GeometryModel3D)asset.Children[0]).Material;
```